# Graduate studies in Number theory

Tags: number-theory

I'm finishing my undergraduate studies in mathematics and I'd like doing research in a future, probably on Number Theory.
That's why I'm interested in graduate program where I could focus on NT. It could be either an only-NT program or one where I could also learn some other topics and at the same time I had the option to choose most of my subjects related to NT.

What I've found so far, resembling what I want is:

[Cambridge Part III](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/postgrad/mathiii/descriptions.pdf)

[Barcelona's University Master](http://www.mat.ub.edu/pop/masters/english/programes.htm). Where the subjects to choose from would be Local Algebra, Complex Analysis, Functional Analysis, Algebraic Curves, Algebraic Geometry, Arithmetic Geometry, Geometry and Topology of Manifolds and Algebraic Number Theory.

[Alagant's masters in Algebra, Geometry and Number Theory](http://www.algant.eu/course.php)

I would be interested in other graduate programs with these characteristics, specially in Europe as it is easier for me to find financial aid.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion: it would be helpul to put the "especially in Europe" at the beginning rather than at the end.  For this type of question, that's quite important: without getting into all the (not necessarily relevant) details, this question coming from a American student sounds kind of weird (for instance, we do not have standalone masters programs of high repute).

Comment: When did Cambridge award a Master's degree for Part III? I know they started splitting Senior Optimes in 1985, another dangerous innovation.

Comment: What languages do you understand?

Comment: @user9325 English and Spanish. I could also do it in French as long as I don't need a language certificate, something really unlikely.

Comment: Note that if you are admitted to a US university Ph.D. program, you will typically receive all necessary financial aid (usually in return for having to do some teaching).  I mention this just because of your remark about preferring Europe for financial reasons.  Also, despite you European preference, let me mention that Boston College has just begun a Ph.D. program, which is strongly focussed on number theory.

Comment: @Matt E. Thanks, the Ph.D. program looks great.